# Error in checkDataset, The given dataset: mmusculus_gene_ensembl , is not valid

Tags: r, biomart

I was perfectly using `bioMart`, but it gave an error, I went ahead trying to follow the following [thread](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/104194/).

And there were some issues with `BiocInstaller::biocLite('grimbough/biomaRt')`, namely, I needed to install `biocLite("remotes")` and then follow the [link](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks--lgfortran-and--lquadmath-error/) to solve `lgfortran error`.

After doing all of that and successfully running `BiocInstaller::biocLite('grimbough/biomaRt')` I still got the same error:

> Error in checkDataset(dataset = dataset, mart = mart) : 
>     The given dataset:  mmusculus_gene_ensembl , is not valid.  Correct dataset names can be obtained with the listDatasets() function.

I am using `MacOS High Sierra`.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: 
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages ...
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was the first bioMart error, and how did you get that error? Why did you install the github (development) version of the package instead of the one in Bioconductor?

Comment: I am not sure why it stopped working, some temporary issue with `biomaRt`, maybe... I switched back to just `biocLite()` installation and it started to work. It would still be interesting to make the development version work.

Comment: Try posting the problem on Bioconductor support site https://support.bioconductor.org/.